# Changing default path of Run Python File in Terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do I change the default path of **Run Python File in Terminal** in VSCode v1.60.1 to be the drive where my code is located? Currently it always starts in c:\users\my_username and all my code is on drive d:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Path of Terminal depends upon which folder is opened in `explorer tab` . So for example  If you open a folder which is located in **e:\code** then the terminal path will be **e:\code**.
Open a new  terminal with `ctrl + shift + ~`   key combination.

Additionally, you can `right` click on a file/folder and  select `open in integrated terminal` which will  also change the terminal path.